# Command to put circuitikz specification in preamble to use it globally

Tags: circuitikz, linewidth

im trying to make global changes in the circuitikz specifications.
I managed to to this with many commands but im struggeling to make two commands global:
(1) transform shape
(2) line width commands

```
\documentclass{report}

% CircuiTikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/width=.4}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/base height=.45}
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos/width=.4}
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos/base height=.45}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos style/nocircle}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{grounds/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.55}
\ctikzset{inductors/scale=0.55}
\ctikzset{capacitors/scale=0.6}
\ctikzset{sources/scale=.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
  
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[transform shape,line width=1pt]
    %Coordinate system
    %\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (6,3);

    %Compontents
    \draw (0,2) to [V_=$U$] (0,1);
    \draw (2,2.8) to [C=$C$,i^= $I_C$] (2,.2);
    \draw (4,2.8) to [R=$R$,i^= $I_R$] (4,.2);
    \draw (6,2.8) to [L=$L$] (6,1.5) to [R=$R$] (6,0.2);

    %wiring
    \draw (0,2) to (0,3) to [short, i^= $I$] (2,3) to (2,2.8);
    \draw (2,3) node[circ]{} -| (4,2.8);
    \draw (4,3) to [short, *-, i^= $I_{LR}$] (6,3) to (6,2.8);
    \draw (6,.2) |- (4,0) node[circ]{} to (4,.2);
    \draw (4,0) to [short,-*] (2,0) to (2,.2);
    \draw (2,0) -| (0,1);
    
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Circuit Example (doesnt really matter):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `circuitikz` is based on `tikzpackage`, so you can insert in premable:

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style = {transform shape, line width=1pt}}
```

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

% CircuiTikz
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/width=.4}
\ctikzset{tripoles/nmos/base height=.45}
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos/width=.4}
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos/base height=.45}
\ctikzset{tripoles/mos style/arrows}
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos style/nocircle}
\ctikzset{tripoles/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{grounds/thickness=1}
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.55}
\ctikzset{inductors/scale=0.55}
\ctikzset{capacitors/scale=0.6}
\ctikzset{sources/scale=.8}
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{every picture/.style = {transform shape,line width=1pt}} % <---

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
    %Coordinate system
    %\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (6,3);

    %Compontents
    \draw (0,2) to [V_=$U$] (0,1);
    \draw (2,2.8) to [C=$C$,i^= $I_C$] (2,.2);
    \draw (4,2.8) to [R=$R$,i^= $I_R$] (4,.2);
    \draw (6,2.8) to [L=$L$] (6,1.5) to [R=$R$] (6,0.2);

    %wiring
    \draw (0,2) to (0,3) to [short, i^= $I$] (2,3) to (2,2.8);
    \draw (2,3) node[circ]{} -| (4,2.8);
    \draw (4,3) to [short, *-, i^= $I_{LR}$] (6,3) to (6,2.8);
    \draw (6,.2) |- (4,0) node[circ]{} to (4,.2);
    \draw (4,0) to [short,-*] (2,0) to (2,.2);
    \draw (2,0) -| (0,1);

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]